# Deleting file from Google Drive by using Google Play Services only

Tags: android, google-drive-api

Actually I can delete file folders by the help of Google client or other libraries but I need to delete file by the help of Google  play services provided methods only.

I Google but not getting the code to delete files by the help of Google Play Services provided methods.

I can upload, download, can create files and folder through this library but don't know about deleting files and folders.